# Deploy document library with multiple content type

Tags: document-library, content-type, document, folder

I have a Document Library definition that I added to the solution. I want to include multiple content types for this Document Library: one that inherits from Folder and one that inherits from Document. I did search on Google but found nothing worthy. I also need this to be inside the Visual Studio project. I can add them manually in the interface just fine, but I have to do it each time I deploy the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already have the content types defined in your project you can do like below.

In your schema.xml, set the attribute EnableContentTypes to TRUE on `<List />` element.
Then declare the content types you want to use like below

```
<ContentTypes>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01Contenttypeid1"></ContentTypeRef>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01Contenttypeid2"></ContentTypeRef>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01Contenttypeid3"></ContentTypeRef>
</ContentTypes>
<Fields>
   <! --List all your fields -->
<Fields>
```